# Angular routerLinkActive not working when navigating using skipLocationChange

Tags: angular, angular-router, angular-routerlink, routerlinkactive

Suppose I have following routes:

```
const routes: Routes[] = [
  {
    path: 'a',
    component: AComponent
  },
  {
    path: 'b',
    component: BComponent
  }
]
```

And I have some Navbar link with `routerLinkActive` class when on path `a` like this:

```
<li
  [routerLinkActiveOptions]="{exact: true}"
  routerLinkActive="is-active"
  class="BottomBar-menuItem"
>
  <a routerLink="../a">A</a>
</li>
```

The problem occurs when I'm navigating from path `a` to path `b` with `skipLocationChange`

```
//component A

navigate() {
 this.router.navigate(['../b'], { skipLocationChange: true, relativeTo: this.activatedRoute })
}
```

The browser url doesn't changes, it still on `/a`, the view is changed to component B, but `routerLinkActive` doesn't apply the `is-active` class.

`routerLinkActive` should still apply the `is-active` class because the url doesn't change, right? What am I missing here?

Comment: is it important to still use `skipLocationChange`? Suggestion: why do you not make 'B' a child of 'A'? Then, the `is-active` state will still apply.

Answer (score 1):

it's happened because you use "**skipLocationChange: true** " and skip the location change in the URL you can see an example in:

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-skiplocationchange

and angular documentation: https://angular.io/api/router/NavigationExtras